# How do you know if the graph starts from above or below?

Tags: graphing-functions

I can't seem to find a way to know if a graph starts from below or above. By that I mean what is pictured below (where the graph starts from the top left).

[image]

For example, in this graph below where the equation is as in the picture, I know that the x values are 0, 1 and 3 but I'd have thought that the graph would start from the bottom left quadrant due to the fact that the x is positive.
**Could someone please explain why in this case it starts from the top left and how to know for other similar cases.**

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you are asking why $y>0$ when $x<0$, it is because $x^2>0, $x-1<0$, $x-3<0$ and "a negative times a negative is a positive."  If this isn't what you're asking, please clarify the question.

Comment: The notion of such a graph "starting" is non-sensical.  You can plot it in any order, or piecemeal, if you like.

Comment: Well, I didn't know how else to start the question.@DavidG.Stork

Comment: That's because the question makes no sense.

Comment: I simply came for some help. Please tell me how I should have phrased it. @DavidG.Stork

Comment: @saulspatz Sorry for any confusion, the answer to what I meant is below. Thank you though!

Comment: So, @Gravity098:  given you accept the "answer" below, tell us all:  Does your graph start "from above" or "from below"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get a few simple examples.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that odd powers have one behaviour at the ends and even powers have the opposite behaviour.  This continues for higher powers.

You want to graph
$$  x^2(x-(\text{don't care}))(x-(\text{don't care})) \\ 
= x^4 + (\text{don't care})  \text{.}  $$
So we expect even power behaviour.

This is exactly what we do when the leading coefficient is positive.  When it is negative, flip the graphs upside-down.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't see how @EricTower's "answer" addresses the stated question.  So, Eric, does the given graph start "from above" or "from below"?  Please refer to the red circle in the OP's problem statement.  Thanks.